# Error when dividing DataFrame values by 255 in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code

I am encountering a TypeError when attempting to normalize the values in a pandas DataFrame by dividing them by 255 in Python. The error message is as follows:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.utils import to_categorical

# Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/NESLİHAN/Desktop/project/data.csv', encoding='latin-1', on_bad_lines='skip')

# Check data types of columns
print(df.dtypes)

# Convert relevant columns to numeric
# Assuming 'column_name' is the column you want to convert
df['column_name'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column_name'], errors='coerce')

# Drop the 'label' column
x = df.drop('label', axis=1)

# Convert x to numpy array after handling data types
x = x.to_numpy()

# Normalize the values by dividing by 255
x = x / 255.0

# Assuming 'label' is the target variable
y = df['label']
y = to_categorical(y)
```

I have checked the data types of the columns using df.dtypes, and I have attempted to convert relevant columns to numeric types. However, I still encounter the TypeError. How can I resolve this issue and successfully normalize the DataFrame values?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `x` is not a number but a string. Check what's in that variable. Without a sample csv. i can't see what type would be expected. if `x = "12"` then a fix would be `x = int(x)/255`

Comment: it seems `x` has strings. You may need to use `x = x.astype(int)` or `x = x.astype(float)` (before `x=x.to_numpy()`)

Comment: My csv file looks like this: id path label                                                                                        
0 0 C:\Users\NESLIHAN\Desktop\project\da... acne_1
1 C:\Users\NESLIHAN\Desktop\project\da... acne_2
 my labels are : acne, bags, redness                                                                                           
 x=x/255: I use this line to scale the image pixels between 0 and 1 by dividing all elements of the array x by 255

Comment: A .CSV file is text (ie made up of string lines). Hence any number is just a string. Reading into a DF preserves the string format; converting to Numpy preserves the string format. So you have to convert to numerical values before using numerical operations.

Answer (score 0):

This error is likely occurring because one or more of the columns in your DataFrame `x` are of type string.

You can try to add `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` which will convert all columns to numeric before the line `x=df.drop('label',axis=1)`.

Note that this might not be the best solution depending on your data if you have string columns that cannot be converted to numeric.

Comment: This time I get an error like this: "ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed."         Is the problem with my csv file?

Comment: Can you showcase your `x` content?